# Building own custom framework base resources in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

We are making our own custom base framework in aosp, this will build as a static jar in out/system/ and package with the system.img.

We need to use our own framework resources also like images and string.xml so that we can access this from our own namespace like how android resources are using in code(For example @android/id,@android/string,R.android.string, R.android.id etc etc)
In AOSP google have a res folder in framework base, which will build as framework-res.apk and will build with framework.jar/android.jar

How we can build our own custome framewok resources so that we can use from my namespace(R.mynamespace.string, R.mynamespace.id etc)

Comment: No one have answer for this

Comment: Hi did you every figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

follow steps.

Add your resource in “/frameworks/base/core/res/res/Resource_Type_Folder” folder

Make an entry in /frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/public.xml file